# Authentication App versus SMS Message for Two Factor Authentication

Tags: two-factor-authentication

Some accounts I've seen offer Two Factor Authentication using an SMS message or an authenticator application. Are one of these options more secure than the other or are they equal?

Comment: There is a lot to this, and implementation matters, so there isn't necessarily a clear winner. SMS and phone are subject to failures from from the telephone network infrastructure, that may allow SMS or call based messages to be sent to the attacker, so many people consider app based to be more secure categorically, but in reality a poorly implemented MFA system using an authenticator app can be even worse. Apps are also subject to social attacks like MFA-bombing. at the core of most apps, is a One-Time-Password Seed that if captured makes it easy to counterfeit. a good app is probably better.